# Why can't FindInstance find a solution to this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

```
FindInstance[680 == 1/3 2^m (-1 + 4^v), {m, v}, Integers]
```

`FindInstance` seems to be unable to find the integer solution $ {m = 3,v = 4} $ in the equation above (failing with the message:

```
FindInstance::nsmet : The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find
the requested instances or prove they do not exist.
```

Is there are technique that can be used to find integer solutions to equations like the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I try

```
FindInstance[680 == 1/3 2^m (-1 + 4^v) && 0 < m < 10, {m, v}, Integers]
```

I get as output `{{m -> 3, v -> 4}}`. So, by restricting the equation a bit, you can find an (integer) solution to such equations. But you should have a feeling for the solution (if you have bad luck and use only `4 < m < 10` then you will not find the solution).

Answer (score 0):

A systematic search returns only one solution `{m->3, v->4}`.